# Discrete math, a bag of marbles problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose you have a bag containing 3 red marbles and 8 blue marbles.
You are going to draw 6 marbles, without replacing them. What is the probability of drawing all 3 red marbles? (an outcome of 3 red and 3 blue for the 6 that you draw.)

Would also like to know the probabilities for the other outcomes (2 red 4 blue, 1 red 5 blue, 0 red 6 blue). How do you find these without enumerating every possible drawing of 6?

Comment: Have you heard of the hypergeometric distribution ?

Comment: What is the probability of drawing $5$ marbles and having them all be blue?  $\dfrac{2}{11}$.  Do you see why this is the same problem?

Comment: Have you tried the brute force strategy? You might be able to work out the faster way once you understand the repetitive part of the slow way.

Comment: Another homework question solved without any effort shown. I think this site should change its name to Math (Homework) StackExchange :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have not yet encountered the hypergeometric distribution. You need not be frightened, it is just another term for drawing without replacement, and the basic formula follows commonsense.

For example, the probability of drawing $2$ red and $4$ blue will be

$\Large\frac{[draw\; 2\; red\; from\; 3\;red\;]\times[draw\; 4 \;blue\; from\; 8 \;blue\;]}{ [draw\; total\; of \;6 \;from\; the\; entire\; pool\; of\; 11]}$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad= \Large\frac{\binom32\binom84}{\binom{11}6}$

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help ! $\;\;$ ;)